# Checkbox controls subform visibility - how to keep it visible when form is reopened?

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-2007, vba, subform

A checkbox controls whether a subform is visible.  If the checkbox is "true," the subform is visible.  The problem is, when I close and reopen the form the subform is no longer visible even though the checkbox is still true.  I have to uncheck and re-check the checkbox before the subform becomes visible again.  Here's what I'm using:

```
Private Sub RefBoardCkbx_Click()
If RefBoardCkbx.Value = True Then
[Admin Sep - Awaiting Prelim SubBox].Visible = True
Else
[Admin Sep - Awaiting Prelim SubBox].Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, there has to be some way for the form to automatically re-run the code everytime it opens--I don't know how to make it do that!

Answer (score 1):

Use the main form's On Load event to make the subform visible when the form opens.

```vb
Me.[Admin Sep - Awaiting Prelim SubBox].Visible = True
```

You probably also want to put a check in the check box at the same time.

```vb
Me.RefBoardCkbx.Value = True
```

As a side point, consider whether this version of the click event procedure makes sense to you ...

```vb
Private Sub RefBoardCkbx_Click()
    Me.[Admin Sep - Awaiting Prelim SubBox].Visible = Me.RefBoardCkbx.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  Changing the subbox format to "visible" solved the problem.

Comment: Spoke too soon!  Both solutions solve the identified problem, but the solutions create an opposite problem.  Now the subform is visible whenever the form opens, regardless of whether the controlling checkbox is "true."  To make the subform invisible, the user as to "check" the box and then "uncheck" it.  I need some mechanism for the main form to verify whether the controlling checkbox is "true" or not whenever the main form loads.  If the checkbox is "true," the subform is immediately visible; if "false," the subform is immediately invisible.

Comment: That solved it.  Thanks.  I had tried everything EXCEPT "On Current"!